# nginx node 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment

I saw a lot of people ask this question but never answerd. I have a node applocation and Im deploying it using nginx. This occured when I try to deploy multiple sites on same instance. But now I have removed one. This is my config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
 
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;


        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

the nginx error log:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just freed the port 8080 and tried installing nginx and pm2 again and it worked.